# TYPO3 v12: How can logged in feusers edit their data?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-12.x

I used TYPO3 some years ago, I remember there were some extensions to do the feuser login and feuser data editing.
As far as I understood the feuser login is now integrated into a sysext (typo3/sysext/felogin).

I wonder how can users edit their data in TYPO3 v12? As I can not find any way to do it with this sysext I think I will need another extension for this? However, I can not find any extension allowing the feuser editing their data, I wonder if I am doing something wrong or overlooking something or am I the first person using v12 having that request?

I analyzed the felogin system extension.
I searched for external extensions at TYPO3 Extension Repository.

Answer (score 0):

We're using the [femanager extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/femanager), unfortunately it is still not adapted to TYPO3 v12.

You can contact the developer and ask him about their update plans or help to migrate it to TYPO3 V12.
You can find [femanager on Github](https://github.com/in2code-de/femanager).